# Slicing a scene corresponding to depth

Tags: rendering, depth-map

I was going through a paper on near eye display by S. KAZEMPOURRADI et al. In the paper, the authors sliced a scene corresponding to distance from view plane using Blender. I am unable to so in Blender.[image: Slicing of scene as in the paper.]
I tried rendering depth map, but I don't know what to do next. Any suggestion/approach will be highly appreciated.
P.S: I varied the values of clip start and end of camera lens to extract various slices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable *Z* (*Depth*) pass for rendering and use some cropping math used for Alpha input.

### Compositor - Map Range node

It is accurate if you want to set specific distance from Camera. In this example scene, the space between Cube and Sphere is 12.5 m from Camera object.

[image]

With this nodetree you can specify Start-End depth.

[image]

... or organised into Node Group for easier use.

[image]
[image]

In this case Cube is visible in depth 9 - 12.5 m

[image]

... Sphere from 12.5 - 14 m

[image]

[image]

By adding these two nodes you can set in Value node Start and under Math (Ad) node you can specify slice depth ... here 1 m and just by changing Value node move 1m slice back and forth.

[image]

For compositing images with depth info *Z-Combine* node is usually used.

### ... Color Ramp

Another option can be *Color Ramp* node, but since depth is cropped by *Normalise* node, that takes closest object's point as 0 and the most far object point as 1, there is not easy way to set distance by metric, but if you need just set visual separation, should work too.

[image]

[image]

If you need to separate objects, you could be interested in *Cryptomatte* feature ... or rendering with *View Layers* ...